# Can't able to build/run Xcode project due to provision profile issue

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Please see this screenshot:

[image]

I have tried the following to resolve this error but no luck.

Try 1

Revoke the certificate and profile app store.(close/open the xcode and compiled d source same issue)

Try 2

Deleted provisioning profile locally from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/.(close/open the xcode and 
 compiled d source same issue)

Try 3

Added new certificate and profile for that id,then downloaded manually and automatically in Xcode both has same results.

Device and simulator both are not building and run

I am using Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12. Projects contain pods. We have an Apple paid account.

This error came on expired provision profile.

Comment: Choose "automatic provisioning" OR in the "Build Settings" search for code signing or provisioning and choose the correct profile for debug & release.

Comment: How to create a provision profile please visit this site and follow these steps : https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-create-a-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-ios/

Comment: You can also check this steps : https://hyperpad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204378199-Create-a-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile

Comment: all above are tried but no luck